# Prequisites for a PDE course (Strauss)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soft-question

This question is quite general. In four days I will enroll in a PDE course which will use Strauss as the textbook. However, today when I checked the course description I found  that 'multivariable calculus' should be a course taken before this course. I took Analysis I & II which basically covered most chapters of Rudin's Principle of Mathematical Analysis (except the manifold chapter). However, I never took Calculus ( Single or Multivariable ) before. Is it OK to enroll in the PDE course?  If not, please mention something which I should master before the course starts.

Comment: Do you know how to take a partial derivative? Or solve a DE?

Comment: @Phill Yeah I know the differentiation of several variables up to inverse and implicit theorem

Comment: Well, I don't know what is true for your specific circumstances, you're refering to specific texts and courses that I can only guess as to the content, but when I remember back (many years now) to when I did a PDE course I was expected to know those things I mentioned. To get a proper answer you should really be talking to a course advisor at your institution.

Comment: @Phill Thanks for replying I will consult with the course instructor.~

Comment: While it's difficult to be sure without knowing more particulars of your institution, I think you'll be ok provided you have some time to fill in gaps in your knowledge. Beware Chapter 7 in Strauss, perhaps you have not seen Green's theorems yet...